# MySQL query 3 columns holding similar data

Tags: mysql

In a database table I inherited the structure contains 3 colums concern1, concern2, concern3.

```
Record 1 may have concern1 A, concern2 B (nothing in concern3)
Record 2 may have concern1 C, concern2 A (nothing in concern3)
Record 3 may have concern1 B, concern2 A , concern3 D
```

I would like to end up with

```
Concern Count
A         3
B         2
C         1
D         1

I can then use this to produce a chart.

My knowledge of SQL is not enough to do this.
```

Comment: *In a database table I inherited the structure contains 3 colums concern1, concern2, concern3.* Unclear. Provide this as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: Looks like you need in UNION ALL then GROUP BY + COUNT().

Comment: moreover, you should use a better normalised database schema. see [database normalisation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Thanks folks.  as I said I inherited this table and structure.  If I get time (big if) I will make concerns a table with a 1 to many relationship.  I will need to find anywhere in the system they are referenced and change code.  More likely I will leave it and use the answer given.  I did get a solution using a temporary table and Insrt Into Select but UNION ALL looks neater.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a union query:

```sql
SELECT Concern, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
(
    SELECT concern1 AS Concern FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT concern2 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT concern3 FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE
    Concern IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    Concern;
```

By the way, having a frequent need to do this sort of query might imply poor table design.  In that case, you might want to maintain just a single column of concerns, along with auxiliary columns for the type of concern.

Comment: This will also return the unneeded row with `Concern IS NULL`.